# How to get a particular frameset functionality in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, frames

I'm coding a page for a company website. We want to be able to click a link in the sidebar and have it open in the same window, beside the sidebar.

This is possible using frames, however I'm using Visual Studio to code the site with ASP.net, and ASP isn't accepting the frameset model. Moreover, I know that frames are generally frowned upon and for good reason.

Is there a way to code the page within ASP to do what we need? I've spent a couple of hours searching and I can find a bunch of ways to set a page up without using frames (which I already knew), but haven't yet seen anything that mentions a way to get a menu selection on the left to open in the column on the right.

Any help?

Comment: Are the links external or internal (i.e. is it third party)?

Comment: Internal. They are to various calendar pages written in html.

Comment: NM - Spent a bit more time digging and found a solution I can tweak here: http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/HTMLGuide/iframes2.htm

Comment: That is, NM unless you can think of a more elegant way to do it. I appreciate the look.